# program work out really fine but receive segfault when debug in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

Here is my test code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
char arr[20]={0};

char* findWord(FILE* fs)
{

      static long pos=0;
      fseek(fs,pos,SEEK_SET);
        char chr[1]={0};
        bool flag1=false;
        bool flag2=false;
        while((1==fread(chr,1,1,fs))&&(!(flag1==false&&flag2==true))){
                                        // This would make the findword() function
                                        // find only a single word once
            if(chr[0]!=32){
                strncat(arr,chr,1);
                flag2=true;
                flag1=true;
            }
            else
                flag1=false;
        }


        pos=ftell(fs)-1;  //this is a little funny.
                          //maybe everytime you use "fseek()", "ftell()", the
                            //file-position will move one byte ahead. 
        return arr;
    }

int main()
{
    FILE* fs=fopen("testfile.txt","r");
    if(!fs){
        printf("Failed to open file!");
        exit(1);
    }
    char a;
    while(1){
        printf("Again?(y/n)");
        scanf("%c%*c",&a);
        if(a=='y'){
        memset(arr,'\0',20);
        printf("%s\n",findWord(fs));
    }
        else
            continue;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this program work out really fine after compiled. It open a file, which only contain some normal characters and spaces(this file have been formatted and contain only normal characters and spaces. not even newline), and then filter out word one by one. For example, if there is a string `I am really fine...` in the `testfile.txt`, then the program will prompt you and then print out `I`, and then `am`, and then `really`, etc.

Anyway, a really simple program. But the very strange thing is, I got segfault at the line `bool flag1=false` when debugging using gdb. And this is only a simple definition!! How could one get segfault at a variable definition?!

Copy this snippet and try it.(remember the change the file name. and make sure that your file contain no newline character until the end of the file).And then use gdb to try again.

Comment: Side note: Why are you returning global variable `arr` for? (p.s., it would be even a worse idea if that variable was local).

Comment: Side note #2: Have a red light turned on for every use of `[]` (and every use of a variable declared with `[]`). This is probably the most common cause in C programs performing a wrong memory access operation (leading to either a memory access violation or a an unexpected result (and in general - undefined behavior of the program)).

Comment: Side note #3: `char chr[1]` cannot store any string besides an empty one. Without even looking at the rest of your code, that's most likely where your problem stems from. The fact that it doesn't always segfault is a mere luck (second thought, you're lucky that it **did** segfault, otherwise you might have ended up experiencing unexpected problems elsewhere without understanding why).

Comment: @barakmanos I only use `chr` to store a single character, rather than a string. see `fread(chr,1,1,fs)...` part.

Comment: It cannot store anything besides an empty string. A null-terminated string with a single character contains **two** characters (the second one being... how surprising... the null character).

Comment: Your indentation is somewhat erratic; in particular the bit around "else continue" is rather misleading. Also, lines like `while((1==fread(chr,1,1,fs))&&(!(flag1==false&&flag2==true))){` aren't terriby readable, both due to layout and logic.

Comment: Well, what I meant to say is - you can store a single character in it, but it will not be a null-terminated string (unless that character is the null character, in which case, it is considered as an empty string). And if it's not a null-terminated string, then you should **avoid** passing it to functions that expect a null-terminated string as input, such as `strcat`, `strcpy`, `strlen` `strcmp`, `printf("%s"...)` and so forth. Deploying the use of `char chr[1]` does not automatically make it a valid C string. In fact, you might as well use a `char c` variable. They are **equally useful**.

Comment: @barakmanos `fread()` require a pointer as a parameter

Comment: @walkerlala: I meant that you could just as well have declared `char c`, and call this function with `&c`. A pointer still needs to point to a valid memory segment, and allocating `char chr[1]` is equivalent to allocating `char c`. That said, I did not say that you **should** use `char c` instead of `char chr[1]`, I said that you **should not** use either one of them for storing a null-terminated string of a single character, because such string requires a memory block (e.g., a variable) of **at least two characters**!!!

Comment: use a pointer to make your string grow one char at a time, not copying whole strings....

Comment: @walkerlala: Please read **carefully** my previous comment (approximately 4 up) on using functions that take null-terminated strings as input.

Comment: @Could you point out the bug in my code or provide any improvement?

Comment: Yeah, declare `char chr[2]`, and set `chr[1] = 0` before entering the loop. And do yourself a favor, study the concept of null-terminated strings until you fully understand it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `strncat(arr,chr,1)` with `arr[strlen(arr)] = chr[0]`.

Comment: Can you show us the output of the gdb command `disass /m findWord` up to and including the line that gdb says is where the fault is?